# Using pagination on a page with url with query string data

Tags: url, pagination

I have an index page that filters entries based on url query strings, eg: `site.com/inductees?county=123`.

I put together a very simple pagination setup with next/prev links. However, when I click "next" I am brought to `site.com/inductees/p2` and I lose my filtered set of entries from the `?county=123` bit.

**How can I get pagination working and keep the query string in my url?**

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to add the additional parameters to the url `<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}?country=123">Previous Page</a>`

Comment: That was excitingly simple. I was thinking of that before I asked this question but assumed it wouldn't work for some reason. Thanks! Make it an answer if you'd like a vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The huge advantage of craft over other CMS is the high flexibility and the ability to customize many things. Thus Craft won't provide non changeable `<a>` tags but links you can change like you want.

```
{% set country = craft.request.getParam('country') %}
<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}?country={{country}}">Previous Page</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

In most Craft projects I do I'll create a pagination include file so anything I need that requires pagination, I can just include that and I get the same pagination pattern anywhere within my site when I need it.

While you do have to set the country attribute with each link, sometimes it might get a little tedious to do this manually or you may expand your attributes to include other options, like `?country=123&distance=50`.

This is where Craft's `craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath()` comes into play. In Craft 3 this has been changed to `craft.app.request.queryStringWithoutPath`. But you could do something like this:

```
{% if craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath() %}
  {% set queryString = "?" ~ craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath() %}
{% endif %}

<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}{% if queryString is defined %}{{ queryString }}{% endif %}">Previous</a>
```

Then no matter what URL attributes you have, they'll always be included within your pagination links.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did use a pagination include file on another, more straight-forward project. This project is an older one, but lots of areas need streamlining... this will help!